# Inverse differencing and inverse box cox on forecasted arima predictions

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, box-jenkins

I am working on a time series project with non-seasonal data which has a non-constant variance. So in order to solve that issue I used box cox transformation to get the data in a suitable format,

```
data %>%
  BoxCox(lambda) %>%
  autoplot()

data1 = data %>%
  BoxCox(lambda)
```

then I observed that first order differencing made the data stationery, so I fitted the following arima model to the data..

```
model <- stats::arima(data1, order = c(3,1,4), method="ML")
```

After which I did my forecasting using the following function:

```
modelforecast = forecast::forecast(model, h=10)
```

now i need to get the data back in the original scale, so I did the following process:

```
boxinvTransform <- function(y, lambda) {
  if (lambda == 0L) { log(y) }
  else { (y^lambda - 1) / lambda }
}

invdiff = diffinv(modelforecast$mean, differences = 1)
forecast_ = boxinvTransform(invdiff, lambda)
```

But the results that I got are nowhere near the scale of the original data...

original data: 456800 397800 383700 501900 417100 454100 434000 403700 566500 472200 445800 496500 523800 549600

the data that i got after the above mentioned process:  -Inf 0.9434329 1.3769624 1.5894133 1.7242389 1.8205814 1.8943596 1.9534444 2.0023330 2.0437477 2.0794921

What am I missing? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "inverse transform" is actually identical to the Box-Cox transform. So you are applying the transformation twice.

The correct inverse transformation would be

```
boxinvTransform <- function(y, lambda) {
  if (lambda == 0L) { exp(y) }
  else { (y * lambda + 1)^(1/lambda) }
}
```

But you are obviously already using the forecast package which includes the `BoxCox()` function. It also includes the `InvBoxCox()` function, so you can just use that.

Even easier, use the built-in transformations in the package which handles it all for you, like this:

```
model <- Arima(data, order = c(3,1,4), lambda = lambda)
modelforecast <- forecast(model, h=10)
```

The resulting forecasts will be back-transformed as required.

Comment: Thank you, that was quite helpful!

Comment: Please see 
https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6304/my-upvoting-policy, 
when you find a question sufficiently clear to 
write an answer, consider to upvote the question!